# can someone help me with this problem of fetching online members?

Tags: php, mysql

When one member is logged in, can see if he/she is online in the panel group but at the same time when another member is logged in, the list is not showing all the two members who is online but it show the current member who logged in in the second time. And if this current member logout it show the first member who logged in at the first time.

what I want is to show all member who logged in.

The table which track  the member_id and the last_activity is:

```
login_id    member_id   last_activity           
26          1           2022-01-03 12:29:16
26          1           2022-01-03 12:36:19
```

when a member login in, the login script will fire the insert data in the above table i.e

```
       $inserted = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO members_details (member_id, last_activity) VALUES (?,?)");
        //the variable in array come from select query i.e the $member
        $inserted -> execute([$member["member_id"], date("Y-m-d H:i:s", STRTOTIME(date('h:i:sa')))]);
        $login_id = $db -> lastInsertId();
        if(!empty($login_id))
        {
            $_SESSION['member_id'] = $member["member_id"];
            $_SESSION['login_id'] = $login_id;
            header("Location: dashboard");
        }
```

now I fetch the user online with:

```
  $onlinemember = $db -> prepare("SELECT members.member_id, members.member_name, members.photo FROM members INNER JOIN members_details ON members.member_id = members_details.member_id WHERE members_details.last_activity > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 SECOND) ");
  $onlinemember -> execute();
```

the foreach statemement:

```
$result =  $onlinemember -> fetchAll();
if($onlinemember -> rowCount() > 0)
{
    foreach($result as $data)
    { 
        $mydata = array(
            'member_name' => ucfirst($data['member_name']),
            'photo' => ($data['avatar'] === "" ? 'default.png': $data['avatar']),
            'you' => (($_SESSION['member_id'] === $data['member_id']) ? '(you)' : '')
        );
    }
echo json_encode($mydata);
```

}

the last query used to update every three 3sec

```
     $update = $db -> prepare("UPDATE login_details SET last_activity = ? WHERE login_id = ?");
     $update -> execute([date("Y-m-d H:i:s", STRTOTIME(date('h:i:sa'))), $_SESSION["login_id"]]);
```

Help me please

Comment: Show how you fetch elements. Maybe you just do `->fetch()` one time instead `fetchAll()`

Comment: So you have something that is updating the user rows of all users constantly?  That's a really bad design.   Also as @Justinas stated, you have some database class you are using, but I don't see you fetching data.  You are asking a question about code not working the way you expect, without showing the code.

Comment: _Side note:_ This: `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", STRTOTIME(date('h:i:sa')))` can probably be replaced by just: `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

Comment: `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 SECOND)` doesn't this query returns only the records inserted before only 5 seconds?

Comment: @groovy_guy - yes rows where that column was updated within the last 5 seconds.

Comment: Another thing that doesn't make sense is using PHP to do the time calculation when you can use a mysql timestamp column and set it to NOW().

Comment: You're overwriting `$mydata` every time you loop. You need another array which you push $mydata into each time, and then encode that array as JSON

Comment: The question was edited@Justinas

Comment: First of all, as @gview mentioned updating the records constantly is really not a good way of designing the system you're working on. second as @ADyson said you are overwriting the `$mydata` array every time you are looping your records

Comment: @ADyson the question was edited, please look back  at jquery

Comment: @adttmkbttmkb why, what do you want me to do? You've already accepted an answer. And your change has no relationship to the comment I made. Why have you changed it, when the question is already successfully answered? If you have a new problem, please ask a new question about it. Do not change an existing question, otherwise all the comments and answers will not make any sense to future readers. Thanks.

Comment: I've rolled back your edits since after the question was solved. Again, if you have a new problem, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your `foreach` as below,

Every time you loop in `foreach` your `$mydata` array overwrites and clears your previous records.

which is why creating another array element in the loop and storing it in your main array works fine as a solution.

```
    $mydata = array();

    foreach($result as $data)
    { 
        $loopdata = array(
            'member_name' => ucfirst($data['member_name']),
            'photo' => ($data['avatar'] === "" ? 'default.png': $data['avatar']),
            'you' => (($_SESSION['member_id'] === $data['member_id']) ? '(you)' : '')
        );

            array_push($mydata, $loopdata);
    }
```

Comment: Yes,  but the simpler syntax is $mydata[] = array(....);  No need to call array_push.

Comment: @gview yes I agree with that too